# Ошибка при получении символов из BufferedReader в ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, linux, сеть, android-spinner

Не получается вытащить список сетевых интерфейсов из BufferedReader в ArrayAdapter и последующим выводом в spinner, список интерфейсов виден (например в логе).

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
EditText editText;
Button button;
Spinner spinnerNet;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    spinnerNet = findViewById(R.id.spinnerNetwork);

    getNetworkInterfaces();


}



public void getNetworkInterfaces () {

    String str = "";
    try {

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "ls /sys/class/net");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            process.getInputStream()));
    int i;
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    while ((i = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0)
        output.append(buffer, 0, i);
        bufferedReader.close();

    // body.append(output.toString()+"\n");
    str = output.toString();




    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerNetwork);

        ArrayList<String>strings = new ArrayList<>();

        strings.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n")));

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strings);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // body.append("Error\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

P.s. Добавил списочный массив ArrayList  strings. Использовал метод str.split и добавил полученные строки как список Arrays.asList в спиннер. Проблема решилась.

Comment: Содержимое activity_main.xml можно убрать из вопроса - оно здесь не играет роли.

Comment: Причём здесь Integer? Вам нужно передать в адаптер список строк. Для этого либо читать поток построчно, добавляя в `ArrayList`, либо разделить полученную строку на подстроки методом [String.split(regex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) , например.

Comment: Получилось вбить в спиннер методом String.split(regex), каждый интерфейс можно выбрать из списка. Есть ли костыли или велосипеды в коде, обновил его

Comment: Не надо так менять вопрос, потому что теперь Ваш код не воспроизводит обозначенную проблему. Лучше дополните а-ля: "P.S. я сделал так-то, проблема решилась, но меня терзают смутные сомненья..."